# Float:left change td width

Tags: html, css

Whith the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/nwcb1gwk/

When i apply `float: left; display: block;` to a `<td>`, the width of `<td>` is change (and the third block is outside).

I need to apply this for use overflow: hidden.

How i can do exactly the same size of the second table with float ?

```
.One {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  //padding: 0px;
}

.All {
  outline: 1px dotted lightgrey;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

div {
  width: 150px;
  zoom: 400%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 0;
}

<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class='All One'>X</td>
      <td class='All One'>X</td>
      <td class='All One'>X</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class='All'>X</td>
      <td class='All'>X</td>
      <td class='All'>X</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve here, but if you're floating table cells then you're going to have a bad time. Maybe Flexbox would be a better approach? https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to giving your table `display:table` and your td's `display:table-cell` and you dont need other codes. Here is all css i think you need;

```
table {
display: table;
}

.One {
display: table-cell;
//padding: 0px;
}

.All {
outline: 1px dotted lightgrey;
width: 50px;
background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Furkan, but with this patch, overflow: hidden don't work :(

Comment: @Florent Let's try to fix it to :) Can you explain where do you need `overflow:hidden` ?

Comment: overflow:hidden is use on the class .All

Comment: @Florent Ok. create a div in your `td` and give it a class(i will call it insideDiv) and create a css class for this div like;

`td div.insideDiv{
  height:25px;
  width:100px;
  overflow:hidden;
}` and write the content in it

Comment: @Florent you can change height and width ofc. Let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to class .One

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

This will include your 1px outline in 50px of td's width. by default it is box-sizing: content-box; which means that width and border are separate.

Answer (score 0):

I have prepare one solution for you ..

Try this one

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

.One {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  //padding: 0px;
}

.All {
  outline: 1px dotted lightgrey;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

div {
  width: 157px;
  zoom: 400%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 0;
}
</style>
</head>


<body>
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class='All One'>X</td>
      <td class='All One'>X</td>
      <td class='All One'  >X</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div>
 <table>
    <tr>
      <td class='All'>X</td>
      <td class='All'>X</td>
      <td class='All'>X</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It will surely works for you.. Thank you

Comment: Are you joking ?